# Select records that don't exist in a union between a table and a subset of that table

Tags: sql

I have a table with appointments, past, present and future. I would like to be able to run a single query that would give me a list of appointments from a given date, with a status of "no show" that DO NOT have an appointment in the table with a date in the future.

So, what I have so far is (pseduocodey)

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
    FROM Appointments
    WHERE Appointments.Date >= Today's Date)
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT *
    FROM Appointments
    WHERE Appointments.PatID = SUBQUERYRESULTS.PatID)
```

The subquery would be

```
SELECT *
FROM Appointments
WHERE (Appointments.Status = "NoShow" AND (Appointment.Date is >= Start_date and <= End_date))
```

I'm not sure how to include the subquery to get it to work. I'm new to this, so please excuse the idiocy.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want `not exists` as a `where` condition.  Based on your description, this seems to be:

```
select a.*
from appointments a
where a.status = 'no show' and
      a.date = @date and
      not exists (select 1
                  from appointments a2
                  where a2.patid = a.patid and a2.date > current_ate
                 );
```

If the date column has a time component, then the date comparison needs to take this into account.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I wanted to do. Sorry for the basic question.

Answer (score 0):

> appointments ... with a status of "no show" that DO NOT have an appointment in the table with a date in the future

This seems to work (tested with Access 2010), and includes "Start_date" and "End_date" comparisons to limit the 'NoShow' appointments to a date range:

```sql
SELECT a1.*
FROM Appointments a1
WHERE a1.Status='NoShow'
    AND a1.Date >= Start_date AND a1.Date <= End_date
    AND NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM Appointments a2 
        WHERE a2.PatID = a1.PatID
            AND a2.Date > a1.Date
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this still does not select any records. It definitely no longer throws an error, so thank you very much, but it doesn't pull anything. I'm not sure what the issue is, but I really appreciate your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option (albeit untested) which uses a `LEFT JOIN` in place of the subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM 
    Appointments t LEFT JOIN Appointments u 
    ON t.PatID = u.PatID AND t.Date < u.Date
WHERE
    t.Status = "NoShow"  AND
    t.Date >= Start_date AND 
    t.Date <= End_date   AND
    u.PatID IS NULL
```

The line `u.PatID IS NULL` essentially performs the selection of those records with no future appointment.

Comment: This works, so thank you! Is there any performance benefit/cost to this vs. a subquery? I'd love to make the subquery work for ease of setting future constraints, but this definitely works. Thank you for your help!